# Candidate template ignored: deduced type does not match adjusted type

Tags: c++, templates, boost, graph

There is a very strange problem with the function call of `remove_edge` in boost graph library.

When I call it in main function, compile and runtime are both ok;
However when I call it in a template function `test_remove_edge`, I get compile error.

The code sample and compile error msg are here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/max_cardinality_matching.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/maximum_weighted_matching.hpp>

using namespace boost;

template <typename Graph>
void test_remove_edge(const Graph& g)
{
   typedef typename graph_traits<Graph>::edge_iterator edge_iterator_t;

   edge_iterator_t ei, ei_end;
   for (boost::tie(ei,ei_end) = edges(g); ei != ei_end; ++ei)
   {
       std::cout << typeid(*ei).name() << ", " << typeid(g).name() << std::endl; // exactly same with the one in main
       remove_edge(*ei, g); // compile error, see message pasted below
   }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    typedef property<edge_weight_t, float, property<edge_index_t, int>> EdgeProperty;
    typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS, no_property, EdgeProperty> my_graph;

    const int n_vertices = 8;

    my_graph g(n_vertices);

    add_edge(1,2,EdgeProperty(5),g);
    add_edge(0,4,EdgeProperty(1),g);
    add_edge(1,5,EdgeProperty(4),g);
    add_edge(2,6,EdgeProperty(1),g);
    add_edge(3,7,EdgeProperty(4),g);

   typedef typename graph_traits<my_graph>::edge_iterator edge_iterator_t;
   edge_iterator_t ei, ei_end;
   for (boost::tie(ei,ei_end) = edges(g); ei != ei_end; ++ei)
   {
       std::cout << typeid(*ei).name() << ", " << typeid(g).name() << std::endl; // exactly same with the one in test_remove_edge
       remove_edge(*ei, g); // compile ok, runtime ok
   }

    test_remove_edge(g);

    return 0;
}
```

compile error msg:

> Candidate template ignored: deduced type
>
> 'undirected_graph_helper >,
>   boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::vecS, boost::vecS,
>   boost::undirectedS, boost::no_property,
>   boost::property >,
>   boost::no_property, boost::listS>::config> &'
>
> of 2nd parameter does not match adjusted type
>
> 'const boost::adjacency_list >,
>   boost::no_property, boost::listS>'
>
> of argument [with EdgeOrIter =
>   boost::detail::edge_desc_impl,
>   Config =
>   boost::detail::adj_list_gen >,
>   boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::vecS, boost::vecS,
>   boost::undirectedS, boost::no_property,
>   boost::property >,
>   boost::no_property, boost::listS>::config]

I am sure that the compiler picks the same overload function `remove_edge` for both cases (Xcode told me). Also I know that the parameter types are the same when calling `remove_edge`, by checking the output of typeid(T).name().

Feeling desperate, many thanks to any help!

Comment: You pass your graph as a `const&`. But you want to change it. So I guess if you pass it just by reference to your function it will work.

Comment: @mkaes oh right right right thank you I wanna buy you a beer!!

Comment: Please in such cases consider just answering, @mkaes. Right now this question is going to stay "unanswered" drawing attention.

Comment: @sehe: I would rather vote to close this question as it does not have any benefits for others.

Comment: Why not both @mkaes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove_edge` modifies the graph, so it cannot be invoked on a const-reference. Simplest fix:

```
template <typename Graph> void test_remove_edge(Graph& g) {
```